# Needs an assist about SAP CLI & CAP Integration

Tags: hana, sap-cap

Currently I trying to $batch request to HDB by SAP CLI, by making Odata v4 sets.

Problem :
On HDB Cloud, It tries to input data with temporal schema, which are consist of random number.
In my package.json, I listed It should use specific schema to use, so data can be input specific table.

The result is, it input data on temporal schema.sometable.

Should I do something to do? It really confuses me - Directly POST an data is INSERT properly.